# How to select an option from a dropdown list and display the values in a form

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

This is in conjunction with an sql database. So basically when a `vehicle_id` is selected from the vehicle database, I want it to display the corresponding `vehicle_model` and `vehicle_year` in the form.

```
    <select name="vehicle_id">

        <?php foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $vehicle['vehicle_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $vehicle['vehicle_id']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        </select><br>

        <label>Vehicle Type:</label>
        <input type="text" name="type"><br>

        <label>Vehicle Model:  </label>
        <input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo $vehicle['vehicle_model']; ?>"><br>

        <label>Vehicle Year:</label>
        <input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo $$vehicle['vehicle_year']; ?>"><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit Vehicle"><br>
```

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: The Problem you are facing is because you're trying to use PHP after the page is loaded. once the page is loaded, PHP cannot help you (without using AJAX calls). You want javascript. Copying your question into google nets some useful answers. [Try starting there](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How+to+select+an+option+from+a+dropdown+list+and+display+the+values+in+a+form)

Comment: How large the list of vehicle options? Is it too large to effectively store in a Javascript array? If so that'll save you querying the database on the server each time someone selects a different vehicle.